# Javascript Object inheritence and async

Tags: javascript, inheritance, asynchronous, firebase

When I have an Object like this in Javascript:

```
var Foo = {

   bar: function(location, callback){

     var ref = new Firebase(location);   
     alert(location); // outputs correct, different value when called twice with different locations

     ref.on('value', function(remote) {
         callback(remote, location);
         alert(location); // outputs last value that was given to Foo.bar, set synchronously, 
                          // but when asynchronously getting the value, only last given to Foo.bar() is retrieved
     }.bind(this)) // bind to .bar scope

   }
}
```

And then do:

```
Foo.bar("some/location", function(remote, location){
   alert(remote) // "some/location"
});
```

This would get back some `remote` object, and the original, requested `location` (which reference I use locally, so when, in whatever order the calls come back, I can put them in the right place in the local client)

Now, when I try multiple `Foo.bar` like this:

```
Foo.bar("some/location", function(remote, location){
   alert(location) // after callback has responded:  "other/location"
});
// some ms have passed, no response/callback from server yet...
Foo.bar("other/location", function(remote, location){
   alert(location) // after callback has responded:  "other/location"
});
```

The `location` variable seems to override the first `Foo.bar()`, which is strange, because as far as I know that variable is in the private scope of `Foo` and should not be touched?

Not even when I do:

```
 var Fuu = Object.create(Foo);
```

Which, as far as I know, would at least create a completely `new Object`, only inheriting the last set variables, but from its inception on out, should be in its own scope. Or am I misunderstanding some fundamental thing here? Or is it the asynchronous `Firebase` library I'm using?

Is the inheritance different when I would do the following? And how/why?

```
var Foo = function(){

    this.bar = function(){

    }

}
```

**To clarify**: After either async calls `callback`, the last `location` variable given to Foo.bar() seems to overwrite the first within the Firebase scope, and I get the right `remote` object, but not the right, associated `location`, which reflects where the `remote` object should go in my client code, locally.

**Update*** I changed `Async()` to `Firebase()` in my question, which I'm actually using, but I don't think it is its fault, because I'm just passing along a variable, and binding it to `this` to keep te reference, but it looks like, *because* `Foo.bar` is the same function(object?), it overwrites the first given `location` variable to the last one that `Foo.bar` received..

**Update** Added `.bind(this)` to the question, to pass the variable to the async function and made the callback function that output wrongly

Comment: Your `Foo` seems to be fine, maybe there is something wrong with `Async`.

Comment: @Bergi [I'm not so sure](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lu5c/)...

Comment: I updated my question, and added the `location` variable to the callback, which is rather essential to my question

Comment: I didn't mean the `Object.create` call (which is not the solution anyway, as the properties of `Foo` are irrelevant to scope). I meant your `bar` function, which *on every invocation* creates its own set of `location`, `callback` and `ref` variables.

Comment: This might be a "feature" of Firebase though, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: What exactly is `Async`? I couldn't find it in the Firebase docs

Comment: Async isn't anything in the Firebase docs. Could you share what you're doing with the Async code? I imagine you're just creating a Firebase reference from a root location.

Comment: @Bergi, as far as I know, you should be able to listen to multiple locations, or even multiple listeners on the same location (which is why you have to make sure to turn them `.off()` when needed. And still, it is a seperate value, that belongs to each instance of `Foo.bar()`..

Comment: How do you know that it's the second callback that fires (where the `location` has an unexpected value), and not the first callback that just fires twice?

Comment: @Bergi, when I don't call it the second time, the correct `location` is returned/alerted, and only once

Comment: try console.log in place of alert

Comment: Shouldn't ref.toString have the location?

Comment: Either way you probably want a new Foo.bar() and then use this to store the location

Answer (score 0):

`this` might answer my question:

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md

> `this` is actually a binding that is made when a function is invoked,
>   and **what** it references is determined entirely by the call-site where
>   the function is called.

This seems to explain my misunderstanding of the `this` binding as well:

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var obj = {
    a: 2,
    foo: foo
};

var bar = obj.foo; // function reference/alias!

var a = "oops, global"; // `a` also property on global object

bar(); // "oops, global"
```

Can anyone confirm that my `.bind(this)` might be the explanation for this unexpected behaviour, and the article is correct?

Comment: The article is correct (as far as I can tell from skimming over it), but your attempt of `.bind()`ing is futile. You did not use `this` in your code, so you don't have any problems with it. You might want to read the [scope chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md#its-scope) again: *To be clear, `this` does **not**, in any way, refer to a function's **lexical scope***. "Unless that scope is the global scope", the article seems to have forgotten to add (which is just source of more confusion)

Comment: While `.bind(this)` might not do exactly what I thought it did, futile it is not, because without it, the `location` variable would not be readable within the Firebase ref callback function.

Comment: No! `location` *is* available in the *scope* [because of **closure**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572). You don't need to do anything explicitly to make it available. Least bind the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) that is not referred to in any way.